# Angular condition and cssclass in same ngClass

Tags: angular

I need to use both condition and class in same "ngClass" is there any possible way?

`[ngClass]="{cssclass1 : object.cssclass1status , object.cssclass2}"`

The bold part is the condition and italic part is a CSS class that can be changed. I have used this options separately like,

```
conditional [ngClass]="{cssclass1 : object.cssclass1status}"

object.cssclass1status : Boolean

classes [ngClass]="object.cssclass2"

object.cssclass2 : string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass in the object to a method and let the method build out the object syntax for ngClass. For example

```
// component.html
<div [ngClass]="getClasses(object)">...</div>

// component.ts
getClasses(obj){
    let classes = {
        'cssclass1': obj.cssclass1status // determine true/false of class one
    };

    classes[obj.cssclass2] = true; // set class name and set to true
    return classes;
}
```

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mixed-angular-ngclass-notation?file=app/app.component.ts) demoing this.

Comment: @DanushkaAmithWeerasingha I've updated my answer. My previous answer only worked if the dynamic class name was a property of the component, not a nested property. So `[ngClass]="{myClass: true}"` would work but `[ngClass]="{object.myClass: true}"` would not work. This is why the method is required.

Answer (score 0):

try like this :

```
<div [ngClass]="(object.cssclass1status && object.cssclass2=='stringVal') ? 'cssclass1' : ''"></div>
```